# Separate schemas or one schema for different queues from different applications

Tags: jboss, oracle11g, jms, cluster-computing, messaging

I've a situation when I've two different applications which are deploed on JBoss 4.2.2. I've a cluster with 5 nodes like this. I've implemented JMS queues which are clustered and I've separate schema for all queues (**JMS_CLUSTER**). Is it better solution to sepreate queue schema's between two applications (**JMS_CLUSTER_1, JMS_CLUSTER_2**) or just leave all queues on one database scheme? I need the best performance. I was reading about some input/output operations on scheme, but I don't know exactly how it works.
I'm using JBoss 4.2.2, Oracle 11g and JBoss Messaging 1.4.2

Comment: Are you using Oracle AQ? There is non-trivial relation between XA(distributed transactions), two-phase commit and separate/multiple schema. Generally if you have two JDBC connections one for JMS(AQ) the other for data access, and they both use the same database and the same schema, then Oracle can avoid using two-phase commit even if both connections use the same distributed transaction.

Comment: Oracle AQ? I don't think so. I'm using https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.3/html/Messaging_User_Guide/conf.persistencemanager.html